# Super Linter Exclude not working on MD files on github actions workflow

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, push, super-linter

I am trying to exclude `.md` files from my super linter because it gets caught every time but can't seem to figure it out can someone help?

```yaml
jobs: 
  super-linter:
    name: Lint code and merge
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Super-Linter
        uses: github/super-linter@v4.10.1
        with:   
          exclusions: |
            markdown: true
          files: ${{ join(github.event.push_request.changed_files, ',') }}

  deploy: 
      runs-on: self-hosted   
      needs: [super-linter] 
      steps: 
        #- uses: actions/checkout@v2  #this is used for if you want to push all source code into runner       
        - name: update code base 
          working-directory: /test_pipe/www/html 
          run: sudo git pull origin master        
        - name: restart   
          working-directory: /test_pipe/www/html
          run: sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I have tried using exclude and ignore but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [github/super-linter](https://github.com/github/super-linter)'s [Filter linted files](https://github.com/github/super-linter/tree/v4.10.1#filter-linted-files) section, you can use the environment variables to include and exclude files i.e. `FILTER_REGEX_INCLUDE` and `FILTER_REGEX_EXCLUDE` respectively.

See its [Environment variables](https://github.com/github/super-linter/tree/v4.10.1#environment-variables) section for more details.

Apart from that, it provides `VALIDATE_*` variants of Boolean environment variables too to enable/disable linting per language so you can use `VALIDATE_MARKDOWN: false` and it should also work for your use case.

---

Not sure why you're using its `with: exclusions` or `with: files` inputs but https://github.com/github/super-linter/tree/v4.10.1 doesn't list anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will just exclude markdown

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Lint Code Base
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # Full git history is needed to get a proper list of changed files within `super-linter`
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Lint Code Base
        uses: github/super-linter@v4
        env:
          VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: main
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          VALIDATE_MARKDOWN: false
```